# How do I deploy a contract when my blockchain isn't syncing?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, synchronization, fast-sync

I would like to deploy a smart contract using truffle but I got problems while syncing the etherum blockchain. There are always blocks left and the syncing process is never finished. I don't want to talk about the syncing problem since there are a lot of open issues on github and questions on this platform and it seems the problem can't be fixed.

My questions what other possibilities do I have to deploy a smart contract? I saw there are some online tools but I'm not sure if I want to past my private key to any of these sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platforms like [INFURA](https://infura.io/) exist to do this if you're having trouble running your own node. Truffle, for example, allows you to [set INFURA as a custom provider](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider). Infura does not handle your private keys.